# How to set Yii2 ajaxCrud modal's activeform input field autofocus

Tags: input, yii2, focus

I have a little trouble:

- How to set Yii2 ajaxCrud modal's activeform input field autofocus?

**I've tried:**

- Set `autofocus` attribute
- Using jquery `.focus()`
- Using jquery `.focus()` with `setTimeOut`

**But the results got same:**

- The blinking cursor focus at input just 1 second then disappear suddenly, and help block show validate errors!

I've set `ActiveForm::begin(['validateOnBlur' => false])`
but got same result and not showing helpblock, input still unfocus after 1s.

What should I do now? Thank you!

**Solved, may other people need:**

```
 $('#ajaxCrudModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $("#mauxetnghiemvitri-code").focus();
    });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should add some delay for focus event

```
$('#ajaxCrudModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mauxetnghiemvitri-code").focus();
    },1000)
});
```